# Content-Length header missing on Mono with Azure Storage SDK

Tags: azure, mono, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

If I call `CloudBlockBlob.SetMetadataAsync` from the Azure Storage SDK (3.1.0.1) updating metadata, all new values are in headers of request. This request is `PUT` and on Microsoft's .NET it contains `Content-Length` header (value `0`). But if I run this under Mono 3.4.0 (exact version below) the header is missing and Azure Storage gives me `411`.

Anybody encountered this? And idea how to fix this (I was not lucky so far to extract test case without Azure Storage SDK)?

Mono:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.4.0 ((no/d4511ef Wed Apr 30 12:04:56 CEST 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

Request from Mono:

```
PUT /XXX?comp=metadata&timeout=360 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WA-Storage/3.1.0.1 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.17020; Unix 3.10.25.0)
x-ms-version: 2013-08-15
x-ms-client-request-id: 910f1ad9-d877-4548-97d9-34d5d67950d9
x-ms-meta-XXX: DEAD8E77A7AB25FE13E121CF3C05A19A215D3CCD
x-ms-meta-XXX: 2013-02-11T09:25:59.0000000+00:00
x-ms-date: Thu, 01 May 2014 17:49:21 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey XXX:XXX
Host: XXX
```

Request from Microsoft's .NET:

```
PUT /XXX?comp=metadata&timeout=360 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WA-Storage/3.1.0.1 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.34014; Win32NT 6.2.9200.0)
x-ms-version: 2013-08-15
x-ms-client-request-id: 5b5ce8ea-ee2a-4a3b-900e-84e6bbeb1642
x-ms-meta-XXX: DEAD8E77A7AB25FE13E121CF3C05A19A215D3CCD
x-ms-meta-XXX: 2013-02-11T09:25:59.9999999+00:00
x-ms-date: Thu, 01 May 2014 17:55:04 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey XXX:XXX
Host: XXX
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be being affected by a recent regression in Mono. But you may be lucky enough to know that it could be already been fixed in [this commit in mono master](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/f647afb02fea54af468d2f164263cae1582d6736). Please compile mono master yourself and test with it. If it still doesn't fix your problem, please report it as a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a minimal testcase.

Comment: I cherry-picked the commit on top of `mono-3.4.0`. Compiling now, let's see how that goes. But from changes in code I see, I'm not sure it's what affects me.

Comment: Yes, it's solved in `master`. Now to just wait for some stable version. Thanks.